# Got left vs have left

Tags: questions

What is the correct form of question:

a) “How many sets do you have left?”
b) “How many sets you have left?”
c) “How many sets you got left?”

And also, what is the rule that I need to use to know when I should put "do" before "you" (I mean "do you have left"/"you have left")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lawrence mentions in his comment, "How many are left?" "How many do you have left?" and, "How many have you got left?" are common and *broadly* interchangeable.  The first is more a question of *existence* while the second two are about *possession*, but in most contexts these mean the same thing, since you would be asking about the ones the listener currently *has*.

> Do you have the sandwiches?  How many **are** left?
>
> How many sandwiches **do you have** left?
>
> How many sandwiches **have you got** left?

"How many **have you** left?" is slightly more formal but otherwise means the same thing.  You may find it more commonly used in certain dialects (possibly BrE).

"How many **you got** left?" is dialect, and very informal. Again, it may be more common and acceptable in the vernacular of certain regions (possibly AmE more than BrE).

Comment: And when playing UNO, the rule is "when you have just one card left, you've to shout UNO!". Can it be: "When you've got just one card left..,.........."? I mean is it likely to be used?